# Warning: Missing argument 1 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 106

Tags: wordpress

I got following warnings.
Warning: Missing argument 1 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 106 and defined in /wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 175

Warning: Missing argument 2 for WP_Widget::__construct(), called in /class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 106 and defined in /wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 175

Can any one please let me know how can i remove this warning?

Comment: Ehh...go to line 106 in your file and set the missed argument(s)?

Comment: Thank bub but it is wordpress core file and i have not idea about wordpress core file change regarding it. can you please share any code for this? may share the code here?

Comment: I got the solution as i disable the all plugin and activate one by one plugin that is need for my website. I hope this is plugin issue but i didn't rectify by which plugin i got this bug.